# Automate script by changing str_detect?

Tags: r, automation

I am using this script to produce a table. In the second line, for collectionName, I am using "Organization X". I have many different organizations (Org Y, Org Z, .....) to create this table for. Is there a way to automate this? And to automate the naming of the object (currently "orgx" below)?

```
orgx <- df %>%
  filter(str_detect(collectionName, c("Organization X"))) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Year, paste(years, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  corpus(text_field = "text") %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_select(stopwords('english'),selection='remove') %>%
  tokens_tolower(keep_acronyms = FALSE) %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = dict, nomatch = TRUE) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Title") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(keyterms, true), funs(round(., 4)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the column names specific to that organizations as vector, use that as pattern in `str_detect` by looping over the vector in `map` and return the output in a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
vec <- c("Organization X", "Organization Y")
out <- map(vec, ~ 
         df %>%
  filter(str_detect(collectionName, .x)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(Year, paste(years, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  corpus(text_field = "text") %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_select(stopwords('english'),selection='remove') %>%
  tokens_tolower(keep_acronyms = FALSE) %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = dict, nomatch = TRUE) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Title") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(keyterms, true), funs(round(., 4)))
)
names(out) <- sub("^(...).*\\s+(\\S)$", "\\1\\2", vec)
```

It may be better to keep the output in a `list`.  But, if we need to assign it to different objects, it can be done with `list2env` or `assign`

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ran the script above. ANd it seemed to work? But how can I see see a table from the output? "names(out)" returns the list organization names from "vec", but I don't know how to see the tables.

Comment: @J.Doe you can either do `out[[1]]` or `out$"Organization X" etc or check for objects created in the `ls()` if you already run the `list2env` i.e. you would be find `Orgranization X', ....I think we can change the names of `OrgX` etc. if you want to

Comment: @J.Doe Updatd the post.  If you run `list2env`.  you can type 'OrgX' can get the output table

Comment: One question, when I view the object, there are single quotes around it? like this 
` Org X `, is there a way to get rid of those?

Comment: Have you tried the updated `names(out) <- sub("^(...).*\\s+(.)$", "\\1\\2", vec)` and then called `list2env`

Comment: Or change it to `names(out) <- sub("^(...).*\\s+(\\S)$", "\\1\\2", vec)`

Comment: I still see single quotes around it. For example doing `View(Organization X)` returns "Error: unexpected symbol in", but doing View(` Organization X `) works. Not a big deal, just curious about is all. Thanks again!

Comment: It is only because of spaces in the name.  But, the `sub` should have removed it though

Comment: What I meant is that you need to check `ls()` again.  It must have created "OrgX", "OrgY" objects now